# Preventing automated attacks on Tokens without relying on Firewall or Network Infrastructure

Tags: brute-force, owasp, owasp-top-ten, user-enumeration

Our concern is more on application side prevention automated attacks. Although the firewall does it part to help prevent this, it has been mandated in our development team's security practices that we need a 2nd level of protection. Solutions such as MFA and CAPTCHA are solutions to a different issue. They help reduce the chances an attacker has to possibly bypass authentication and guess the credentials. What we want here is just basically to detect an automated attack and stop it (or realistically, delay it).

The attack the penetration tester did was this:

http://ourapplication.com/passwordreset&token=AAAAAAbbbbCCCCDDDD####3333KkOoBvVNNJIKGDDVL

This is a link sent to email addresses for password reset. They tried automated enumeration of the token to be able to guess a correct one. Although they were not successful guessing a valid one, they still filed this as a vulnerability since our application failed to catch this automated attack and was not able to block the requests. So, we now have been in a dead end finding solutions for this.

Some solutions we have come up with:

1. IP Address blocking - seems problematic since requests go through a number of servers and components (firewall --> web server --> app server etc.), it would be extremely difficult to get the source ip address of the requester. Sometimes attacks still could be behind proxies.

This would be doable if the enumeration was something like username and password. We can come up with a logic that detects enumeration of usernames with the same password and start blocking next requests using the same password. In this case, only a token in the input.

Running out of reasons to solve this issue. Can anyone help  us on this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly: Isn't they way you construct the link already sufficient protection against brute forcing, i.e. couldn't you open the algorithm you use to construct the link to the pentesters and successfully argue that it is practically impossible to brute force a link due to the design of the link and that a 2nd line of defense would not add any more protection? Or would in the current design the link actually be guessable so that an additional protection could actually mitigate a risk?

Comment: Additionally, your application could simply react slowly to any kind of password reset link. This would slow down any kind of brute forcing without actually significantly affecting  a valid reset link. And the link could also be valid only for some time, include the IP address it was requested from and expect the same when calling the link etc.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i get what you mean. thats what i initially told them. token is virtually unguessable. But its not about that, they said they managed up to 40k iterations of guessing the token and no action whatsoever from the app to block the requsts

Comment: *"...they managed up to 40k iterations of guessing the token..."* - again, just react slowly to any kind of password reset link. And ask them for their specific expectations on how the application should behave and which additional security this is supposed to achieve.  A good pentester should be able to explain the actual objectives of a requirement and if it is actually relevant in a specific use case. It is not clear here if they are just trying to tick checkboxes without actual understanding or if you fail to understand what they actually want.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich their objective is to prevent the app from attacks from automated mechanisms . I think we can handle it programmatically if it was username and password. We can catch request using same password but enumerated usernames. The problem here is there is only one input - the token

Comment: @davshowhan449: *"... their objective is to prevent the app from attacks from automated mechanisms ..."* - this specific objective is already achieved by using unguessable links by design. A 2nd line of defense does not actually add value here. So the pentester should explain what this 2nd line of defense should actually achieve, apart from letting them tick the checkbox.